# NestJS: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, nestjs, backend, interceptor

I am trying to create an API interceptor just to learn a bit about them. I wrote a simple app but I get the following error:

> Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client.

All the API response interceptor should do is check if the data is of type `APIResponse`. If so, then call `toResponse()`, which adds a success field based on status. I did this purely for practise reasons. Although I get the response is expect, I also get the error is mentioned earlier. I do not know why and where the code is trying to set the headers a second time.

This is the controller class:

```
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get()
  async getData() {
    console.log('getData');
    const data = this.appService.getData();
    return APIResponse.success('Welcome to weight-journal-api!', data);
  }
}
```

This the service class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  getData() {
    return 'test';
  }
}
```

I made a class with static methods to return `APIresponses` to stay consistent with what I return:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Response } from 'express';

@Injectable()
export class APIResponse {
  constructor(
    public status: number,
    public message: string,
    public data: any
  ) {}

  //the api.response.interceptor.ts will use this method to send the response back to the client
  toResponse(res: Response): void {
    res.status(this.status).json({
      success: this.isSuccess(),
      message: this.message,
      data: this.data,
    });
  }

  private isSuccess(): boolean {
    return this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400;
  }

  //Controllers will use these methods to return responses

  static success(message: string, data: any): APIResponse {
    return new APIResponse(200, message, data);
  }

  static created(message: string, data: any): APIResponse {
    return new APIResponse(201, message, data);
  }

  static error(message: string, data: any): APIResponse {
    return new APIResponse(400, message, data);
  }

  static notFound(message: string, data: any): APIResponse {
    return new APIResponse(404, message, data);
  }

  static conflict(message: string, data: any): APIResponse {
    return new APIResponse(409, message, data);
  }
}
```

Here is the API interceptor itself:

```
import {
  CallHandler,
  ExecutionContext,
  Injectable,
  NestInterceptor,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Response } from 'express';
import { APIResponse } from './api.response';

// This interceptor is used to intercept the response of the API and send it back to the client
@Injectable()
export class APIResponseInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const response = context.switchToHttp().getResponse<Response>();
    return next.handle().pipe(
      tap((data) => {
        if (data instanceof APIResponse) {
          data.toResponse(response);
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

here is the app.module

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { APP_INTERCEPTOR } from '@nestjs/core';
import { APIResponseInterceptor } from './shared/api.response.interceptor';

@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
      useClass: APIResponseInterceptor,
    },
    AppService,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Anyone that knows why I get this error?

Comment: You're trying to change the incoming status of a response in `toResponse` which has had it's headers already written (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client).  In general it's also bad practice to reuse and manipulate objects you don't own in that fashion:  there may be unintended side-effects to either the owner and you can't ensure who else may have a reference to the underlying data.  If you need to pass on a response object where you can change the code create a new one.